# To get username in all the session

Tags: spring, jsp, session, spring-mvc

I want it to do, it is very simple but the result is not like I want.

I want to show the username in all app when the user are logged, but I show the username in the first page.

My code is:

Controller

```
...    
@SessionAttributes("username")
public class InitController
{
@RequestMapping(.. RequestMethod.GET)
public String request (ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request)
{
   ...
   //model.addAttribute ("username", name);
   request.setAttribute("username", name);
   ...
   return "pageToShow";


 }
}
```

Page .jsp

```
<header>
    <div id="divHeader">
        <h1><fmt:message key="page.header"/></h1>
        <div class="divUser">
            <a href="direction?id=${username}" >${username}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The .jsp page is always present because it´s header

Thanks.

Comment: please remenber scope of @SessionAttributes("username") will remain to only that InitController Clazz. It will not available if your request is emanated from Another Controller than InitController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
request.setAttribute("username", name);
```

with

```
model.addAttribute ("username", name);
```

and replace

```
<a href="direction?id=${username}" >${username}</a>
```

with

```
<a href="direction?id=${sessionScope.username}" >${sessionScope.username}</a>
```

When you use `${username}` you print the `username` MVC model attribute which exists only till the end of the current request. `${sessionScope.username}` will take `username` attribute from the session attributes where it was saved by your `@SessionAttributes("username")` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I have tried this and It now doesn´t paint anything, neither the first page nor the rest

Comment: I did not notice that the line was commented out. I updated the answer.

Comment: There are other ways to set a value in the session attributes. For example you could do that: `request.getSession().setAttribute("username", username)` and remove `@SessionAttributes("username")`.

Comment: Perfect!!
Thanks very much. This has been the solution!! ;)